# Remove menu item from sidebar

Tags: wordpress

Someone created a menu in wordpress sidebar. I need to remove that permanently. Can anybody say how can we do that? In this image ( the wordpress dashboard image which you going to see when open this link below ) you can see portfolio, careers, team etc. These are the links someone added before and we need to remove. Thanks :)

http://dev.netbramha.in/projects/image/Untitled.png`enter code here`

Answer (score 3):

You can remove menu items using action hook.

```
function remove_dashboard_menus(){
    remove_menu_page( 'wpcf7' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_dashboard_menus' );
```

remove_menu_page parameter you can pick up from address URL page parameter like this : **http://localhost/wpdemo/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpcf7**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CPT UI plugin, you can open it in your admin and you will find the portolio cpt created there. Just delete from there.

If you are not using CPT UI plugin, you can go to functions.php and remove the code where portfolio code is defined.

Comment: Hey Arshad Hussain, thanks for the reply. But the problem is we are not using CPT UI plugin and I couldn't see "portfolio" in function.php. That's why I'm so confused.

Comment: But in screenshot, I can see there is a menu called "CPT UI" in admin sidebar just after "SEO" menu.

Comment: Sorry brother. CPT is activated.

Comment: That was my mistake

Comment: Have you found "portfolio" section in CPT?

Comment: If the answer is helpful to you, please mark it as accepted so that it is useful for anyone BRO.

Answer (score 0):

In functions.php check add_action() function. You can find these menu items there.